# Why is this jquery ajax call not returning data from my php script?

Tags: php, jquery

I'm new to jQuery, and have not been able to debug this ajax call in Firebug:

This is my ajax call:

```
var styndx = $('#studylist option:selected').val();
var studyname = $('#edit_field').val();
            
    
$.post("saveStudyName.php", {'type': 'update', 'studyname':studyname, 'styndx':styndx},
    function(resultmsg) {
    $('#edit_field').val('');
    $('#savebtn').attr('disabled',true);
    refresh_studynames();
});
```

And this is the function refresh_studynames:

```
function refresh_studynames()
{
  $.ajax({                                      
     url: 'getStudyNames.php',                  
     data: "",                                                             
     dataType: 'json',               
          error: function() {
            alert('Refresh of study names failed.');
          },
     success: function(data)
     {
        $data.each(data, function(val, sname) {
        $('#studylist').append( $('<option></option>').val(val).html(sname) )
      });
     } 
  });
}
```

Finally, this is the php script getStudyNames.php ($dbname,$dbconnect, $hostname are all populated, and $dbconnect works; the backend database is Postgres, and [pg_fetch_all](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.pg-fetch-all.php) is a Postgres function in PHP that returns result as an array):

```
$dbconnect = pg_pconnect("host=".$hostname." user=".$dbuser." dbname=".$dbname);    
    if (!$dbconnect)    {
        showerror(0,"Failed to connect to database",'saveStudyName',30,"username=".$dbuser.", dbname=".$dbname);
        exit;
    }
    
    $sql = "SELECT ST.studyindex,ST.studyabrv AS studyname
            FROM ibg_studies ST
            ORDER BY studyname";
    

    $fetchresult = pg_exec($dbconnect, $sql);
    if ($fetchresult) {
        $array = pg_fetch_all($fetchresult);
        echo json_encode($array);
    } else {
        $msg = "Failure! SQL="+$sql;
        echo $msg;
    }
```

Any help much appreciated....

Comment: Do you see any JSON content when you browse directly to getStudyNames.php?

Comment: The line ` $('#studylist').append( $('<option></option>').val(val).html(sname) )` looks wrong. Why `val(val)`? Where is #studylist emptied?

Comment: Try: `   var $studylist = $('#studylist').empty();
   $data.each(data, function(i, record) {
    $studylist.append( $('<option/>').html(record.sname) );
   });
`

Comment: @Beetroot-Beetroot Put it in an answer

Comment: yes, I do get json output when I browse to getStudyNames.php; good tip!

Answer (score 1):

The line

```
$('#studylist').append( $('<option></option>').val(val).html(sname) );
```

looks wrong.

I'm not too sure but you could try :

```
var $studylist = $('#studylist').empty();
$data.each(data, function(i, record) {
    $studylist.append( $('<option/>').html(record.sname) );
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, Beetroot; will try this code as soon as debug saveStudyName.php, because it is not updating the record, and I do not see how I can debug a .post ajax call....

Comment: This helped, but is not an answer that seems to work; am going to start a new post to address this; the other tips were helpful.