# How do I iterate over this json array and populate a selectlist?

Tags: jquery, json

Despite other similar examples, I cannot quite get this each loop to work to populate a selectlist...but I'm really close!

Per my [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13755304/why-is-this-jquery-ajax-call-not-returning-data-from-my-php-script), I am returning a json array using a PHP script, based on another question that got partially answered. The script, getStudyNames.php, returns this json array:

```
[{"studyindex":"1","studyname":"ADHD"},{"studyindex":"24","studyname":"ADHD_RD"},{"studyindex":"20","studyname":"AFL"},{"studyindex":"42","studyname":"AFRICANERS"},{"studyindex":"2","studyname":"AHD"},{"studyindex":"22","studyname":"AJS"},{"studyindex":"3","studyname":"ASA-FS"},{"studyindex":"4","studyname":"ASIAN"},{"studyindex":"5","studyname":"AUS TWINS"},...]
```

However, I cannot quite seem to get the syntax correct on how to parse this array, then add it to a selectionlist.

Here is my code that attempts to do this:

```
$.ajax({                                      
      url: 'getStudyNames.php',        //the script to call to get data          
      data: "",                        //you can insert url argumnets here to pass to api.php
                                       //for example "id=5&parent=6"
      dataType: 'json',                //data format
      error: function() {
        alert('Refresh of study names failed.');
      },
      success: function(data)          //on receipt of reply
      { 
        var $studylist = $('#studylist').empty();
        $data.each(data, function(i, record) {
          $studylist.append('<option value='.record.studyindex.'>'.html(record.studyname) );
        })
       } 
    });
```

I know that getStudyNames.php works, per the output above; but why this studylist is NOT working is still a mystery to me...appreciate any help!

Comment: is that a `html()` function inside the `append()` function, or just a typo ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try by putting following in `success`.

```
var $studylist = $('#studylist').empty();
$.each(data, function(i, record) {
   $studylist.append($("<option/>", {
        value: record.studyindex,
        text: record.studyname
    }));
});
```

Comment: Bingo! Thanks Ghazanfar Mir...(jquery syntax is a new one on me!)

Answer (score 2):

Looks like there are some typos in the append, and periods are not used for concentenation in javascript, that's PHP, and in javascript that would be the `+` sign.

Try creating the element first, makes it easier to see whats going on, and then append it:

```
$.each(data, function(i, record) {
  var elem = $('<option />', {value: record.studyindex, html: record.studyname});
  $studylist.append(elem);
});
```

Comment: +1. This should work. Random, but what is this `$data` in the front I was wondering also

Comment: @mcpDESIGNS - good eye, that probably should'nt be there, as the `$.each()` function would be the correct way to iterate an object ?

Comment: Yeah `$.each()` would work, think that's what @rixter meant to be using

Comment: @rixter - you do of course realize that the accepted answer is an exact duplicate of this one ?

Comment: No, I did not realize that...is it recommended protocol to award an accepted answer in both cases?

Answer (score 1):

`$data.each(data, function)`

should be

`$.each(data, function)`

`.html()` is incorrectly nested in `.append()`

you're not closing your `<option>`

`'<option value='.record.studyindex.'>'`

should be

`'<option value=' + record.studyindex + '>'`